How to make this subquery return more than one row?
I select data from temporary table:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "tmp" 
(
    "fuel_type" TEXT,
    "litres" NUMERIC(8,2),
    "is_rent" BOOLEAN
);

insert into tmp values ('petrol', 10, False);
insert into tmp values ('petrol', 20, False);
insert into tmp values ('diesel', 20, False);

Like this:
SELECT
    (SELECT row(fuel_type, SUM(litres)) 
     FROM tmp 
     GROUP BY fuel_type);

In case there more than one fuel_type in tmp, I get this error:

SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I expect this output
ARRAY_AGG
fuel_type|litres
petrol,40
diesel,20


why do you need array agg ? and why does the output show petrol = 40 instead of 30

You don't need most of the code you've written. SELECT FuelType, SUM(Litres) as Litres FROM tmp GROUP BY FuelType works just fine, without the need to use ROW or an array agg.


Answered in your staging question.: select array_agg(t.*) from  (select fuel_type, SUM(litres) as litres from tmp group by fuel_type) as t; or simpler yet: select fuel_type, SUM(litres) as liters from tmp group by fuel_type;. 2) Also from there CTE and Aggr functions. Spend time with the docs.


Please before considering posting: Pin down
code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error
message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your
question/problem/goal, with & without your particular
names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many
answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal &
unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at
[meta] & [meta.se]. How much research effort is expected of Stack
Overflow users?
[ask] [Help]

The way your query was constructed was the issue. Try this below code instead to get the expected output.
WITH FuelSums AS (
    SELECT 
        fuel_type, 
        SUM(litres) AS total_litres
    FROM 
        tmp2
    GROUP BY 
        fuel_type
)
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG(CONCAT(fuel_type, ',', total_litres), '; ') AS fuel_data
FROM 
    FuelSums;


Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a
question? Also: Code-only posts are poor. Explain the problem & the solution. Also: The question is clearly an easily found old old beginner duplicate & should be closed not answered. [answer] [ask] [Help]

Why in the world would you jump through all these hoops and write all this unnecessary code (and added overhead) when you can just use SELECT FuelType, SUM(Litres) as Litres FROM tmp GROUP BY FuelType? There is absolutely no reason to use STRING_AGG for the output the OP wants.

It is not clear what realy is your expected result. Select comand results with rows and columns when data was found. From your expected result I could not (without reasonable doubt) conclude was it one or two rows nor one or two columns (putting aside unexplained ARRAY_AGG above it).

If you want 2 rows of data in 1 column named "fuel_type | litres":

Select    Concat( fuel_type, ', ', Sum(litres) ) as "fuel type | litres"
From      tmp
Group By fuel_type

 __________________
|fuel type | litres|
|------------------|
|diesel, 20.00     |
|------------------|
|petrol, 30.00     |
 ------------------


If it was 2 rows of data in 2 columns (fuel_type and litres):

Select    fuel_type, Sum(litres) as litres
From      tmp
Group By  fuel_type

 _________________
|fuel_type| litres|
|---------|-------|
|diesel   |  20.00|
|---------|-------|
|petrol   |  30.00|
 -----------------


If it should be 1 row of data in 1 column named "fuel_type | litres":

Select    Distinct STRING_AGG(Concat( fuel_type, ', ', litres ), ' 
') Over() as "fuel type | litres"
From      ( Select    fuel_type, Sum(litres) as litres
            From      tmp
            Group By  fuel_type
          )

 __________________
|fuel type | litres|
|------------------|
|diesel, 20.00     |
|petrol, 30.00     |
 ------------------  

See the fiddle here.
